# Count grouped by values from UNION ALL

Tags: mysql

I have the following query in mySQL

```
`SELECT * FROM (select assoc1 from fab_cbd where tournament = 65   
union all    
select assoc2 from fab_cbd where tournament = 65) x`
```

Using this I get the full list with values for these two columns. What I want to do is to group by these values and count the occurrences.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then add `group by`:

```
SELECT assoc, count(*)
FROM (select assoc1 as assoc from fab_cbd where tournament = 65   
      union all    
      select assoc2 from fab_cbd where tournament = 65
     ) x
GROUP BY assoc;
```